# How to select a different schema in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, schema, database-schema

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.3 and I have connected to MySQL database.

I want to select a different schema in Oracle SQL Developer but it is giving an error.

**Here is my syntax:**

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = classicmodels;
```

I found this syntax on [Docs.Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general009.htm) but still wondering why it is not working!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just do `schema.table` when you need to access `table`?

Comment: You mean this ?

ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = classicmodels.customers  

its not working

Comment: No, I mean if you want to do `SELECT * FROM table1` do it like `SELECT * FROM schema.table1`.

Comment: That's helpful. Isn't there a way to select schema in the start once and then work like in MYSQL we use "USE <<scehmaname>>  ?   

What is the use of this command then? 
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = classicmodels;

Comment: The set current_schema allow only to skip using schema name before the table or using synonym, but your user stay the same and if your connected user does not have rights to this table, you will get error on select. You did not show here the error.

Comment: Thanks, I have a question when creating a table how do we specify the schema name before table name in syntax. Right now whenever I create a table without specifying the schema name it creates the able into the specific schema but I want it to create in the other schema. Thanks a million

Comment: You can create table in another schema, when you specify the schema_name.table_name, but you need CREATE ANY TABLE privilege and DBA don't like to give any 'ANY' privilege. Another way is to use procedure in the target which executes dynamic SQLs and grant execute privilege to your user, but this is against the security logic in Oracle.

Comment: The normal way is to have a script with DDL and execute it connected with user 'classicmodels'.  Why you want to create table as another user.

Comment: I guess SQL Developer fires some sql on background and possibly reverts your changes.

Comment: Mottor and others it's working I can create a table now using for example :-
CREATE TABLE schemaname.tablename :) Thanks all of you